# Why isn't my Fuji X100S optical viewfinder displaying an overlay?

Tags: viewfinder, fujifilm, fujifilm-x100

I've just got an X100S. I've tried everything but I can't seem to get the overlay to display over the optical viewfinder.

The manual seems to suggest it should just always be on.

Answer (score 3):

You can turn the overlay on and off with the **DISP/BACK** button (page 21 of the manual).

You can customize what's shown in the overlay (pg. 75) with **DISP.CUSTOM SETTING**, and that includes the framing grid.

I should also caution you against wearing polarized sunglasses and shooting in portrait mode, which is the way I managed to inadvertently make the overlay disappear. ;)

Comment: On my X-Pro1, the LCD and EVF (and OVF overlay) are polarized 90 degrees to each other, so at least one of them works in portrait or landscape orientation when wearing polarized sunglasses.